# How to fix this for_url error ("SyntaxError: '/upload' is not a valid selector") in Flask?

Tags: html, url, flask

I have the following problem in Flask,

In my templates folder-

I have three HTML files:

- index.html
- database.html
- upload.html

server.py

```
 from flask import Flask, url_for,redirect, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('index.html')

 @app.route('/upload')
 def upload():
 return render_template('upload.html')

 @app.route('/database')
 def database():
return render_template('database.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{ url_for('upload')}}">Upload    File</a>

  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{ url_for('database')}}">Protein    Database</a>
```

The error I get on the web console on Firefox:

```
 SyntaxError: '/upload' is not a valid selector bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
```

Error from Chrome:

```
Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '/upload' is not a valid selector.
at Object.getSelectorFromElement
```

How can I fix this error please, any help would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks,

Ishack

Comment: This worked for me. Do you have additional content in your html/css files that is not posted?

Comment: in my static folder - I have this file: bootstrap.bundle.min.js